# Xml Schema Pattern To Not Allow Whitespace At The Beginning, Inside Of, Or At The End Of A String

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, whitespace, xmlserializer

I have elements in my xml schema that are of type string. I need to restrict the string, however, to disallow any whitespace at the beginning, end, or "inside" the string and also have a length of at least 1.

Here are some values followed by what I would expect the validation to result in:

```
"HELLO" (Valid)
"H" (Valid)
"" (Not Valid) [length = 0]
" HELLO" (Not Valid) [starts with space]
"HELLO " (Not Valid) [ends with space]
"HEL LO" (Not Valid) [contains a space]
```

I know how to make a simple type which restricts string and I know how to require the length to be at least 1:

```
<xs:simpleType name="MyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Now I just need a pattern to add to my simple type that does what I need.

Can someone tell me what pattern to use?

Thank you.

NOTE - I am not using a program like Xml Spy to validate my Xml documents. I am writing a C# program that serializes/deserializes Xml documents using XmlSerializer.

The reason why I bring this up is because I have read various other posts about Xml schema and white spaces and using xs:whiteSpace = preserve, collapse, replace. I don't think that XmlSerializer handles this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [regular expression pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256481.aspx) is what you are looking for. Something like:

```
<xs:simpleType name="MyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[^\s]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Note that space before/after value may not be actually part of value unless `xs:whiteSpace = preserve`. Consider reading following sections of the XSD specification [White Space Normalization during Validation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#d0e1654) and [Built in data types:string](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#string).

Comment: That worked thanks! :) Do you also know what pattern I would use to validate that a string does not start with or end with a space? I don't care if it has spaces in the middle I just don't want spaces at the beginning or end. For example "Hello There" would be valid but not " Hello There" and not "Hello There ".

Comment: @JanTacci something like (untested, use one of many regex tools to try): "[^\s].*[^\s]|[^\s]" (not-whitespace followed by any number of any chars followed by not-whitespace OR single not-whitespace).